# CD-Rom does not show up in My Computer

Tags: windows-7, troubleshooting, compact-disc

I have OptiPlex 755, Windows 7 32-bit, Intel Core 2 Duo.

Just until recently I did not had to use CD-reader , so I did not even realize that I don't have CD-reader connected to the motherboard.

After I connected both power and data cables, CD-reader would not show up in My Computer.

I updated drives, performed multiple "Scan for Hardware Changes".

In device manager everything looks fine.

[image: Device Manger- (Disk Drives)]

I tried using different data cable, but nothing changed.

I cant see can't see CD-reader in CMD.

CD-reader is able to open and it looks like it is loading the disk because it flashes a green light. 
I did not try to change CD reader.

Microsoft Ifixit, was not able to recognize the device.

Is there anything else that you would suggest?

Comment: `Disk Drives` is your hard drive, please post a screenshot of the `DVD/CD-ROM Drives` category expanded, and also confirm that it matches the model of your drive.

Comment: You have *Disk drives* expanded on the screenshot. At the bottom of the screenshot, there's also *DVD/CD-ROM drives*. Have you looked in there?

Comment: Be aware that even though it wasn't connected to the motherboard, that sata port probably isn't turned on in the BIOS, but you want to make sure you can see it in the BIOS as well. If it isn't in the BIOS, it won't be in Windows.

Comment: I have uploaded a new screenshot, I will check BIOS settings

Comment: BIOS setting are ok but nothing has changed

Comment: The issue is solved, I had to switch data cables for CD-drive and Hard-Drive.  After reboot everything works fine. Thanks